# Is there a more direct way to set up a planning node in ompl?

Tags: ros, path-planning, urdf, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!
I've been reading about how to use ROS for a robotic arm path planning for a while and I actually got some feedback about a doubt I had in [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/29154/need-help-with-rrt-star-algorithm-for-robotic-arm) topic.

For what I see, I'll have to write my own c++ code to define the StateValididyChecker procedure.

Now, I also understand the URDF of a robot has all the physic information one could need to extract the collision information, so isn't there a direct way that uses the URDF for the planning algorithm instead of defining a StateValidityChecker? Or am I just missing it?

Thanks a lot for the help. I'm hopping some day I could be the one answeing questions here :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31501/is-there-a-more-direct-way-to-set-up-a-planning-node-in-ompl?/) by [Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1919/carlos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Carlos,

Have you tried the [arm_navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation) stack together with the Warehouse Viewer?
It works like a charm for my (non-PR2) robot and I found it quite straight forward to set it up using the provided tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2012-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0